# Laravel custom validation for three inputs

Tags: php, laravel

I need to make a custom validation rule where for these three inputs where net_weight = loaded_weight - empty_weight

```html
<fieldset class="form-group">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text">empty weight</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="empty_weight"
         name="empty_weight" min="15000" max="35000" step="20" oncopy="return false"
         onpaste="return false">
   </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
   <legend class="h5 text-center text-danger">loaded weight</legend>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="loaded_weight"
         name="loaded_weight" min="35000" max="120000" maxlength="6" step="20"
         oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false">
   </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
   <legend class="h5 text-center text-danger">net weight</legend>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-lg font-weight-bolder" id="net_weight"
         name="net_weight" maxlength="5" step="20" oncopy="return false"
         onpaste="return false">
   </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: You need to validate on server side or client side ?

Comment: server side validation

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: using laravel 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create yourself a custom validation rule using:

```
php artisan make:rule EqualToNetWeight
```

That will create a new `Rule` class named `EqualToNetWieght` at `app/Rules`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class EqualToNetWeight implements Rule
{
    private $loadedWeight;

    private $emptyWeight;

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($loadedWeight, $emptyWeight)
    {
        $this->loadedWeight = $loadedWeight;
        $this->emptyWeight = $emptyWeight;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return $value == $this->loadedWeight - $this->emptyWeight;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'The net weight does not equal the loaded weight minus the empty weight.';
    }
}
```

I've customised the `messages()` function to be more appropriate and descriptive for this use case.

The `passes()` function is where we perform the validation checking, in this case that your calculation (`net weight == loaded weight - empty weight`) passes and return the result (`true` or `false`) of that calculation.

The values of `loaded weight` and `empty weight` are accepted via the `constructor()` function.

To use the rule you would do something like:

```
'net_weight' => [
    'required',
    new EqualToNetWeight($request->loaded_weight, $request->empty_weight)
]
```